# Can a html5 app download HTML files and store them locally?

Tags: database, html

Is it possible to download html files and images from a server and store them in the same disk location as the html file doing the downloading?

I need to do this because I have an app that is a database of HTML files and these files change from time to time. When updates occur, it would be good if the HTML5 app prompted the user to do an update and if accepted, the file were downloaded and replaced the old file set.

The app has to work offline, hence the need to download the data.

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, yes. Read about the cache manifest http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

Comment: I need to download 50Mb of different files all at one time. The cache manifest is only for storing files once viewed.

Comment: The browser is supposed to download all the things listed in the cache manifest up-front. I suspect there is a size-limit, but I don't know what it is.